# Twitter-bootstrap XS - no toggle menu, carousel broken down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap template to build a custom theme (site is in demo online [here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/vyskoveprace/), you can check it if needed). Everything looks and works fine, but when it comes to "xs" size (less than 768px width) I get into troubles:

- menu is not displaying correctly (toggled in the corner)
- carousel got completely broken - sliders are showing separately not as usual in one carousel

Does anyone have a hint how to fix it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Carousel code (simplified the texts and number of items):

```
<div class="container slideshow">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-454586">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
            <img alt="slider" src="http://localhost/vyskoveprace/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/2_640_250.jpg">
            <div class="mask"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption col-md-6">
                <h2>Header1</h2>
                <p>Some Text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="item">
            <img alt="slider" src="http://localhost/vyskoveprace/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/1_640_250.jpg">
            <div class="mask"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption col-md-6">
                <h2>Header2</h2>
                <p>Some text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The navbar part:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',                
                'container'         => '',
                'container_class'   => '',
                'container_id'      => '',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            ); 
        ?>
        <?php get_search_form( $echo ); ?>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: You're using a container inside a row and without a column. I suggest a review of the Bootstrap grid docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @isherwood said, there needs to be container outside a row and with a column, that was a correct answer to my problem.